# Jqplot graph appears only on first submit

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, post, dialog

I have the following jQuery code to execute when I click a button

```
$('#substat').click(function() { 
    $.post('ext/engine.php', post, function(data){
        $('#statout').empty().append(data).dialog(
         {height:350, width:700, dialogClass: 'shadowme', position: 'center'})
        }); 
});
```

UPDATE - I have checked code by code to see where the problem is. As it looks, it is the PHP part which looks like this:

```
$html = '<script>';
for($s = 0; $s < $m; $s++) {
    if ($m-$s != 1) { $var1 .= $out[total][$s].', '; $var2 .= $out[age][$s].'", "'; }
    else { $var1 .= $out[total][$s]; $var2 .= $out[age][$s].'"';}
    if ($out[total][$s] > $max) { $max = $out[total][$s]; }
}
if ($max > 10) { $max = round($max/10); }
$html .= 'VarH = ['.$var1.'];
    plot1 = $.jqplot("statout", [VarH], {
                legend:{show:true, location:"ne"},
                title:"Gente",
                series:[ { label:"VarH", renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer } ],
                axes:{
                    xaxis:{ renderer:$.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer, ticks:['.$var2.'] },
                    yaxis:{ min:0, tickInterval:'.$max.', autoscale: true }
                },
                seriesDefaults:{ lineWidth:5, rendererOptions: { barWidth:5, barMargin:5, barPadding:0 } }
            });
    </script>';
echo $html;
```

If i change the last line from **echo $html;** to **echo "Hello";** it will always work.

But if i leave it with the $html variable created with jqplot it will only work one time when rendered inside the jquery dialog. After that I have to refresg the webpage to make it work again instead of just clicking again on the submit button to create the dialog with the graph in it.

Comment: Updated to include the PHP code.

Comment: Update2 - I can change the graph anytime if i leave it opened. It will change everytime i click on the submit button so it can change the graph inside the dialog BUT if i close the dialog the graph does not show until I refresh the webpage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. The solution is to display the dialog first and afterwards (!) load the chart into.

Comment: Do you have an idea how to load it into the dialog afterwards taking into consideration that the dialog must be hidden at all times before popping the graph out.

Comment: Thank you wmask for this answer. I spent a good deal of time trying to understand why my chart was not visible within the dialog before I read your answer !